# supporting code to be backward compatible

Tags: java

I have a model (dto) v1

```
SampleDto {
instVar1 
instVar2 
setters / getters 
}
```

This model will be deployed in jboss as modules as part of some services. 
I need to call this model to build my application and this model is my compile time dependency for my application to build.

Now my application to be backward compatible for the below scenario: 
A new member variable say instVar3 (now model version is v2) added; 
my application uses new model v2 as compile time dependency; how can I avoid nosuchmethodfound error if my application runs on model v1 at the runtime.

To handle this, I'm using reflection API to check whether the particular method / field is supported or not in that SampleDto, if supported then use the method otherwise not.

```
final List<Method> methods = new ArrayList<Method>(Arrays.asList(SampleDto.class.getDeclaredMethods()));
for(Method method : methods){
    if (method.toString().contains(methodToFind)){
        log.debug("method supported at runtime - SampleDto");
        SampleDto.newSetter(....);
        break;
    }
}
```

Is this a right handling? Any better way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't it work to just add new methods. Older sdks wont allow calling it while newer will.
When you want to remove a method mark it as deprecatd an log a warning. After a while you can just remove it.

Comment: for ex. the application server has older service(v1) deployed and the app built by new SDK will call the new method, which in turn would fail by saying nosuchmethodfound. i want to provide backward compatibility for the app to work in older service (v1) as well. the new method should be called only in the new service (v2) and as mentioned above, that is how i check whether the method available or not at runtime.

Comment: In your old sdk leave the ols methods. In the new one leave them too but mark them as deprecated. New methods will not be available in your old sdk. Thus when you call a new method you will get exception without throwing it yourself.

Comment: I misunderstood. In that case your code is fine but you should inform the user that something he tried to run can&#39;t be run. Also I'd recommend using reflection to call the method.

Comment: yes, i have a warning message to show to the user if the method was called and not supported. when you say, call a method using reflection, what is the benefit that does compared to the code that i have shown above?

Comment: @NielsNet could you please reply to earlier comment?

Comment: I suspect you do not call the method itself but a wrapper. In case this wrapper is compiled with your source Code and misses the class it calls reflection prevents a compile time error.